# Angular 2+ downloading image from server

Tags: angular, image, express, download

I am working to download image from server using express api, Image data is receiving in front end in special characters form, but image does not download. I want to download the image.

Front end code:

```
downloadFile(data: Response) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
  }

  downloadData() {        
    this.workshopService.downloadData(this.workshop.id)
      .subscribe((result) => {
        this.downloadFile(result)            
      }, error => {
        console.log(error)           
      });
  }
```

Observable which creates http get request:

```
downloadData(id) {
    let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/download-data/';            
    return this.http.get(`${apiUrl}${id}`)         
      .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }
```

Express js api:

```
router.get('/download-data/:id', function (req, res, next) {       
    Workshop.findById(req.params.id).then((task) => {            
        res.download(task.workshopData,'me.jpg')
    }).catch(next);
});
```

Please help, how to download the image that is receiving now in special characters notation. I am getting this response from server, I think the image is receiving in base64 format.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to tell angular that you want response as stream rather than json. Use following code:

```
import { ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';


downloadData(id) {
    let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/download-data/';            
    return this.http.get(`${apiUrl}${id}`, { responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer })         
      .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }
```

Replace service with following:

```
downloadFile(data: Response) {
    console.log(data);
    // may be you need to use data._body to get data of body
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
  }
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Getting syntax error after adding { responseType: "arraybuffer" }, error message says:  Argument of type '{ responseType: "arraybuffer"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.

Comment: Image is still not showing in new window. and not downloading

Comment: Can you paste screenshot of response of browser. Do you got buffered response from server?

Comment: I have edited the question and provided the screen shot of data coming from server.

Comment: Your response is looking fine. Server is sending base64 encoded image. Can you replace your code. I updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162889/discussion-between-sandip-jaiswal-and-waleed-shahzaib).